# Can Hbase use local file system instead of DFS for distributed mode?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have working hbase instance in Standalone mode.
I am planning to migrate it to Distributed mode ( cluster of 3 machines).
My question can i migrate from stand alone mode to distributed without loosing data from stand alone mode ?
Also is it necessary to use HDFS in distributed mode ?

Answer (score 0):

(H)adoop(D)istributed(F)ile(S)ystem. This is the thing which facilitates a distributed Hbase. If you use your native FS, it won't be distributed anymore. So, that is not an option. Distributed implies that the storage(along with computation) is spread across all the participating machines which is opposite to what the native FS does.

Coming to your first question, you can do that. Migrating from stand alone mode to distributed mode should just be a matter of copy from local disk up to HDFS. It wouldn't be hard to confirm this for yourself. Make sure you have setup the Hadoop cluster properly first. Take the backup of your Hbase data as a precautionary measure.

Comment: Thanks Tariq .. 
So i have following in my standalone mode hbase-site.xml

  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/vimal/HBASE/hbase</value>
  </property>
 and updated hbase-site.xml for pseduo distributed mode is 

  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase</value>
  </property>    
So now , i should copy all files from "file:///home/vimal/HBASE/hbase" to "hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase". Am i right ? How do you do that ? Sorry if this is silly question.I am newbie to both hbase and hadoop.

Comment: Yes Vimal. You are right. As @Arnon sir has said you could use distcp to do that. If your data is not too huge, even "bin/hadoop fs -put /src /dst" would also do.

Comment: Hi Tariq .. I tried using "hadoop fs -put file:///home/vimal/HBASE/hbase hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase" but it ran silently and did not copy data as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As Tariq said you need a distributed FS for HBase to work. regarding copying your data over you can try [distcp](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/distcp.html)

Comment: Hi Arnon sir , i tried using distcp using following command :-
hadoop distcp file:///home/vimal/HBASE/hbase hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase
where first argument is my data source in standalone mode and second one is data source in pseudo distributed mode , but i am getting below exception :-
Copy failed: java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8021 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
is it because  hbase is down in standalone  mode as i am migrating  from standalone to pseudo distributed mode on same machine ?

Comment: If you're doing everything on the same machine, I guess your best option is to copy the hbase folder over from HDFS to the regular os (hadoop fs -get or -copyToLocal) on the standalone and then set up the distributed environement and copy the data back (hadoop fs -put or copyFromLocal)

Comment: Hi Arnon Sir ,
In standalone mode , i am not using HDFS , so all my data is in regular OS files. Now on the same machine i am changing from standalone mode to pseudo distributed mode . so i need to import these regular os files into HDFS files right ? How do i do that ? I tried distcp and hadoop fs -put but as i said above , they are not working . Please tell me i am wrong somewhere ..

Comment: As I said you can do use hadoop fs -copyFromLocal to copy files unto HDFS

Comment: Hi Arnon sir,
I followed your instructions .
I copied files from stanalone mode to HDFS using  
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/vimal/HbaseData/hbase/ hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase/
where first argument is hbase.rootdir in standalone mode and second argument is hbase.rootdir in pseudo distributed mode.
Files are copied properly and i verified it using hadoop fs -ls /hbase and it works fine.
However i am unable to see tables in pseudo distributed which i had created in standalone mode.
What could be the cause ?
Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: If the files are there you now need to make hbase know about them (e.g. hbase keeps some of the data in zookeeper etc.). you're next step is to "repair" hbase try ./bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.hbck.OfflineMetaRepair and or hbck commands http://hbase.apache.org/book/apbs04.html#d2576e12550

Comment: Thanks Arnon sir .. I tried your instructions from scratch and now its working fine.